# Multiple view not updating variable in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service

I am using a Factory in Angular JS to share data between 2 controller/sub-views using router-ui.

Factory:

```
app.factory('SharedData', function() {
  return {data: {}};
})
```

JobsController:

```
app.controller("JobsController", function($scope, $http, $resource, $location, $stateParams, JobsService, $state, SharedData) {
  SharedData.data = JobsService.query();

  $scope.data = SharedData.data; 
});
```

NavController:

```
app.controller("navController", function($scope, $state, SharedData) {
  $scope.data = SharedData.data;
});
```

jobs.html

```
{{data.jobs.length}} // this updates fine
```

nav.html

```
{{data.jobs.length}} // this does not update
```

Instead I have to do this:

NavController:

```
app.controller("navController", function($scope, $state, SharedData) {
  $scope.data = SharedData;
});
```

jobs.html

```
{{data.jobs.length}} // this works fine
```

nav.html

```
{{data.data.jobs.length}} // this now works but not sure why the extra 'data' is needed?
```

Obviously I'm doing something wrong here but I can't figure out what despite googling for quite a few hours... can anyone help?

Comment: I suggest loading 'jobs' data in SharedData before instantiating the two controllers. This can be done by using StateProvider's [resolve property](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki).

Answer (score 0):

This quirk has to do with the order of allocation.

When `SharedData` is initialized, it is an object with a single property, `data`, which is an empty object.

When `navController` is initialized, it's `$scope.data` is set equal to the empty object `SharedData.data`.

When `jobsController` is initialized, it ***replaces*** `SharedData.data` with an entirely different object.  *After this*, `$scope.data` is set to equal this new object, but `navController` is still pointing to the original empty object.

In your second example, `navController` isn't pointing to this object soon to be replaced.  Instead, it is pointing to the `SharedData` object itself, so `$scope.data.data` will always resolve whichever object currently exists on `SharedData`.